# A bug in a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nazym/1/   
The code meant to show a popup when button pressed and hide it when pressed anywhere else. The error happens when the button is clicked twice.
So the code should work on showing/hiding the popup when the button is clicked repeatedly.

Comment: I can not.I have built my whole website using pure JavaScript. I cannot implement a library for a single feature. Another thing is that I want to enhance my JavaScript coding skills. That's why I do not use libraries.

Comment: ok then. i'll see what I can do.

Comment: I have just commented your event click code which you have written several times. Have a look on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nazym/11/) and i guess its working as expected.

Comment: Those codes meant to make the button just like every other element when clicked and the popup is visible. When the button is clicked again the popup hides. I will consider your solution if there is not another work around

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi: Avoiding JQuery does not "enhance your Javascript coding skills". It merely means that you haven't learned how to use one of the most widely used Javascript libraries. It's a tool, not a crutch.

Comment: @duskwuff - There's nothing wrong with learning how to do these things without a library. Personally I love jQuery, but some work environments don't allow (external) libraries.

Comment: @duskwuff Some people do not want to use a library for lots of different reasons. See this question: questions/1822651/are-there-any-good-reasons-not-to-use-jquery-instead-of-plain-old-javascript

Comment: Perhaps a more suitable title would be a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make it such that clicking the button shows the popup if it is hidden and hides it if it is shown (and clicking anywhere else hides it), it's this block of your code that is causing the issue:

```
if (ele == element) {
    hideDropDown();
    return;
}
```

You are not passing in any arguments to your hideDropDown function. It should be:

```
hideDropDown(ele);
```

That way, the onclick handler is properly added to the element.

Answer (score 1):

That seems a very complicated way to implement this functionality. You can do it with much less code as follows:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    document.getElementById("window").style.display = 
        document.getElementById("but") === target ? "inline-block" : "none";
};
```

That is, on a click on the document, check if the target/source element was your button: if so show the popup, otherwise hide it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nazym/12/

Or if you'd rather repeated clicks to the button toggled the display of the popup but clicks anywhere else hide it just modify the condition slightly:

```
document.getElementById("window").style.display = 
    document.getElementById("but") === target &&
    document.getElementById("window").style.display === "none" ? "inline-block" : "none";
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nazym/13/

**EDIT**: To cater to your comment that clicking on the popup shouldn't hide it, you could add this code after the above:

```
document.getElementById("window").onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    if (e.stopPropagation) 
        e.stopPropagation(); // W3C model
    else 
        e.cancelBubble = true; // IE model
};
​
```

That is, prevent clicks within the popup from bubbling up such that they don't reach the document-level click handler that does the show and hide.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nazym/16/

Comment: I was just about to edit my answer to include basically this. Nice. :)

Comment: And now it's not working when the popup element contains a set of elements. when the popup is clicked, the popup disappears. http://jsfiddle.net/nazym/14/

Comment: Well your question did say _"and hide it when pressed anywhere else"_ - and the popup is within the scope of "anywhere else". So now you're saying the requirement is to hide it when pressed anywhere other than the button _or_ the popup? OK, I've updated my answer to cover that. See the new demo.